# NewspicksのPick時のUI再現方法

Tags: ios, swift

NewspicksのPick時(シェアとコメント)のUIを再現したいです。
具体的な要件は以下です
１．ボタンが押されると画面全体の半分程度のUIView(=answerView)がappearする。
２．画面全体のうち,answerViewでない部分を押すと、answerViewがdisappearする。

現在はpickボタンが押されるとaddSubviewでAnswerViewControllerのViewを出現させています。しかしこれでは、スクロールで画面全体が動いてしまいます。
求めるUIを実現するにはどうすれば良いか教えて下さい。

```
  func tapPickView(){
    var storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Answer", bundle: nil)

    var controller : AnswerViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AnswerVC") as! AnswerViewController
    controller.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    var answerView = controller.view
    self.view.addSubview(answerView)
}
```